# Automate Memtest86

Tags: server, scripts, live-usb, automation, memtest

I've looked around and haven't seen anything like this so here we go.

I want to put Memtest86 on a bootable USB and then have it automatically run through tests 0 and 1. (Preferably I would like to configure this but we'll assume these two for now.)

Is there a way to write a script or to install Memtest such that when it is run it will automatically run through only those tests instead of starting the standard test?

Comment: Question: Is there a specific problem that you're trying to solve with memtest? Is your computer freezing/crashing/etc? What leads you to believe that there might be a memory problem?

Comment: I am looking for a low cost and fast way to do a manufacturing test on RAM for a product we are installing ram on. If there is a better alternative for this than I would love to hear it.